Pyside2 to Pyside6 eventFilter hover not returning QHoverEvent for position()
I'm trying to move things over to Pyside6 from Pyside2. I've installed an eventFilter with the intent of it grabbing the position when hovering over a certain widgets viewport(). As far as I can tell eventFilter is sending:

<PySide6.QtCore.QEvent(QEvent::HoverMove)>

While in PySide2 it would send:

<PySide2.QtGui.QHoverEvent object at 0x0000029D4AC5DDC0>

In Pyside6 I can't get .position() and it's driving me nuts.
Here's a quick example where it works in pySide2 but not in pySide6 (aside from the imports and the .pos() to .position()).
from PySide6 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore


class TestWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setMinimumSize(500, 500)
        center_widg = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(center_widg)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(layout)

        self.tree_view = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["colm_01", "colm_02"])
        self.tree_view.setModel(model)
        self.tree_view.viewport().setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_Hover)
        self.tree_view.viewport().installEventFilter(self)

        layout.addWidget(self.tree_view)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj == self.tree_view.viewport():
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.HoverMove:
                print(event.position())

        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)





def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    dialog = TestWindow()
    dialog.show()

    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


It seems that the event is not automatically cast as it should. I don't have PySide6 so I cannot test, but if it used to work, it should now, and it may be a bug. What PySide version are you using? PyQt provides cast from the sip module, it's not clear to me if PySide allows something similar (possibly using getCppPointer() and wrapInstance()?).

Currently using the latest version 6.7.0. I've seemed to have fixed it by accident.
I ended up needing to use "qtpy" module due to this being a transitional period. Whatever it's done the eventFilter is sending the correct type of QEvent and it's still running pyside6 supposedly.

It looks indeed a bug specific to 6.7.0: PYSIDE-2675. 6.7.1 should fix that, in the meantime try using PYSIDE6_OPTION_LAZY=0 python3 <your script>
